# Compare all records from one table to all records from another table

Tags: sql, cursor, frequency

I need some help. The goal of my query in SQL is to calculate the frequency of one variable (cars) in a particular garage for a period of time, using the results from two separate queries (Results A + B).

The first set of results (Results A) provides a list of cars in a garage with its respective arrival date and exit date (each record is one car, one arrival date, and one exit date). The second set of results is a CTE recursion using @PeriodStartDate as date and @PeriodEndDate as date, providing results (Results B) with all the dates from the Start Date to the End Date.

From here, what I want to do is take every record from Results A, and compare it to every record of Results B, effectively determining whether the first record/date of Results B is 1) >= to the arrival date, and 2) < than the exit date. E.g. if a car was in a garage from 2016-02-04 to 2016-03-15, and that the Period Start and End dates are 2016-01-01 to 2016-03-01, I want to take this car's record, and compare its arrival and exit dates to all the dates from 2016-01-01 to 2016-03-01, and then have the process repeated for every car/record in Results A.

After this exercise is done, I want the query to yield the amount of cars that were present in the garage per date from 2016-01-01 to 2016-03-01.

To date, the queries for Results of A and B are done, but I honestly have no idea as to how I start the next part.

Thank you,
Mikey

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Edit you question and provide (simplified) data that explains what you want to accomplish.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Count(*) AS TotalCars, B.PeriodStart, B.PeriodEnd
FROM A
JOIN B
ON A.Arrival <= B.PeriodEnd 
AND A.Exit > B.PeriodStart
Group By B.PeriodStart, B.PeriodEnd
```

This would return the total number of cars that arrived before the period ended and exited after the period started

you could change

```
AND A.Exit > PeriodStart
```

To

```
  ISNULL(A.Exit, Getdate()) > PeriodStart
```

To capture cars that have not yet exited for the last period

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I took what you provided as a basis for my query (that now works). I did the same as you, and added a WHERE clause (WHERE "Date from Result B" >= Arrival Date + Variable AND "Date from Result B" < Exit Date) and joined A to B.